Can `unstable_cache` work at build time in nextjs?
I have a react component that wants to use unstable_cache to fetch data from database. I want to achieve the first the when the component receive the request, it fetches from the database and catch it for a few hours, all subsequence requests within the cache hours will not hit database.
export async function generateStaticParams() {
  console.log('start running generateStaticParams');
  const countries = await api.product.countries();
  const c = countries.map((country) => ({
    country,
  }));
  return c;
}

async function Page(country: any) {
  const product = await unstable_cache(
    async () => {
      
      if (country && PRODUCTS[country]) {
        product = PRODUCTS[country];
      }
      return Promise.resolve(product);
    },
    ['product'],
    { revalidate: 3600, tags: ['product'] }
  )()

  return (<div> 

  ...

When I run next build I got this error:
Error: Invariant: incrementalCache missing in unstable_cache

I am using node18 and the dependencies I have is:
"dependencies": {
    "next": "13.4.7",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.14",
    "postcss": "^8.4.21",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.7",
    "turbo": "^1.8.5",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5"
  }

Does anyone know if unstable_cache work at build time? If not, what is the best way to solve it?
After change the component to be async, I got this error:
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.


I`ve just dealed with it couples days ago.
Create something like 'shared_cache.ts' in your route folder and export your fetch function wrapped in unstable_cache, but don't call it right away.
Import it in server component (if you need initial data) and call it, pass data to Child, then import it again in Child component and use it with useEffect or whatever! gl!
